# dplyr conditional summarise

Tags: r, dplyr

I have a working solution, but is there a `cleaner` or more `efficient` one, when summarizing data?

The following data frame:

```
set.seed(101)
dtf <- data.frame(group=rep(c("A", "B", "C"),each=5),
                  item_id=sample(1:1000,size = 15,replace = F),
                  days_to_sale=sample(1:20,size = 15,replace = T))
```

I calculate the following table (where counts are cumulative)

| group | count_items | sold_in_1_d | sold_in_5_d | sold_in_20_d |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | 5 | 0 | 3 | 5 |
| B | 5 | 1 | 1 | 5 |
| C | 5 | 0 | 0 | 5 |

With this code

```
dtf%>%
  group_by(group)%>%
  summarise(count_total=n(),
         sold_in_1_d= length(days_to_sale[days_to_sale<=1]),
         sold_in_5_d= length(days_to_sale[days_to_sale<=5]),
         sold_in_20_d= length(days_to_sale[days_to_sale<=20]))
```

But I would like to change `length()` to `n()` and maybe shorten the subsetting?

Are there better, cleaner solutions?

Answer (score 0):

I think adding new variable to `dtf` instead doing it in summarise part are more simpler to do it:

```
dtf$day_sale_1 <- dtf$days_to_sale <= 1
dtf$day_sale_5 <- dtf$days_to_sale <= 5
dtf$day_sale_20 <- dtf$days_to_sale <= 20

dtf %>% group_by(group) %>% 
summarise(sold_in_day1 = sum(day_sale_1), 
          sold_in_day5= sum(day_sale_5), 
          sold_in_day20 = sum(day_sale_20))

  group  day1  day5 day20
  <chr> <int> <int> <int>
1 A         0     3     5
2 B         1     1     5
3 C         0     0     5
```